Phantom Plotly Gauge Charts In Streamlit
In my streamlit app that is hosted locally streamlit seems to try and render plotly gauge charts when it isn't supposed to. These charts appear transparent opposed to the usual opaque color.
Transparent
Opaque
The issue appears when I click the checkbox "MTR" which changes what is displayed on the page to show the gauge charts. When I uncheck the "MTR" checkbox though to go back to what is displayed by default one row of 3 gauge charts appears transparent when not charts should be.
Here is my simplified code which reproduces the issue I am running into.
import streamlit as st
import plotly.graph_objects as go

st.set_page_config(page_title='example', layout='wide')
colcheck1, colcheck2, colcheck3 = st.columns([1,1,4])

with colcheck1:
    mt = st.checkbox('MT')

with colcheck2:
    mtr = st.checkbox('MTR')


def mtr_page():
    col1, col2 = st.columns([3,10])


    with col1:
        fig = gauge_3()
        st.plotly_chart(fig)
        fig = gauge_3()
        st.plotly_chart(fig)

def gauge_creation(fig, value,title,domain):
    if value >= 90:
        color = 'green'
    elif value >=60:
        color = 'yellow'
    else:
        color = 'red'

    fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
        mode='gauge+number',
        value = value,
        title=title,
        domain=domain,
        number={'suffix':'%'},
        gauge={
            'axis':{'range':[0,100],'tickwidth':1, 'showticklabels':False},
            'bar': {'color':color},
            'borderwidth':1
        }
    ))
    return fig

def gauge_3():
    fig = go.Figure()
    gauge_creation(fig,92,'30day',{'row':0, 'column':1})
    gauge_creation(fig,92,'90day',{'row':0, 'column':2})
    gauge_creation(fig,92,'1year',{'row':0, 'column':3})

    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color='white',size=15),
                            x=0,
                            y=.12,
                            showarrow=False,
                            text='Name',
                            xref='paper',
                            yref='paper'))
    fig.update_layout(
        grid = {'rows':1, 'columns':4, 'pattern':'independent'},
        width = 500,
        height = 100,
        margin = {'t':50, 'b':10, 'r':26, 'l': 18}
    )
    return fig

def test_blank():
    col1, col2 = st.columns([1,2])
    with col1:
        st.write('hi')

if mtr == False and mt == False:
    test_blank()

if mtr:
    mtr_page()


I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but I would guess that if you check the MTR, the initialization of the graphs should be performed and the graphs should be displayed, as I inferred from the behavior of repeatedly clicking the MTR, graphs are added one after another, the earlier ones being made transparent and the latest one active.

@r-beginners What is happening is when the checkbox is selected the page display should change from the default when it isn't selected. On the default page all that should be displayed are the checkboxes and text that says "hi". When "MTR" is selected the new display then shows the checkboxes and 2 rows of 3 gauge charts. When unselecting "MTR" and going back to the default display one of the 2 rows gets displayed, but transparent almost like it knows it shouldn't display it yet it still does and like you mentioned if you repeat this process a row of 3 gauge charts are added each time. Thanks!
